# Intuitionistic fragments of classical logic

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic

For what conditions on `P` and `Q`, does `P ⊢ Q` in classical logic imply `P ⊢ Q` in intuitonistic logic (for higher-order logic, though of course results for more restricted logics are relevant too)?

Comment: There are many results of this form, usually restricting $P$ and $Q$ to "negative fragments" or restricting their complexity (to, say, $\Pi^0_2$ statements of arithmetic). Can you give more context about what kind of result you're interested in (and why)?

Comment: @cody I'm interested in generalizing http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~danr/papers/intuit.pdf (CEGAR loop for IPL satisfiability) to more powerful logics (using also http://profs.sci.univr.it/~bonacina/talks/MSR2016sggs-slides.pdf (DPLL-style procedure for first-order logic) and maybe a higher-order version of that). Basically, for (some?) intuitionistic fragments an intuitionistic validity procedure can just use a classical satisfiability procedure.

Comment: For first order logic, the term you want to search for is “Glivenko classes”. Probably, similar characterizations and techniques apply for higher order logic. See: http://www.helsinki.fi/~negri/glivenko_classes.pdf

Comment: @UlrikBuchholtz why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @cody sure, done!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As requested, I'm turning my comment into an answer:

For first order logic, the term you want to search for is “Glivenko classes”. Probably, very similar characterizations and techniques apply for higher order logic. See Sara Negri's [Glivenko sequent classes in the light of structural proof theory](http://www.helsinki.fi/~negri/glivenko_classes.pdf).